# How to import or render HTML page in react application?

Tags: reactjs, mern

I have created a navigation bar that has Home, contact us and about us tab in react application. My contact us page made in html. So, I want to render contact us HTML in react application.

Comment: Please provide reproduciable code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
   you can use react router for this purpose Have a common component for header where all your links reside and make 3 seperate components with home, contact, about and navigate to each of them based on user actions
install following packages into react App
1. npm install react-router --save
2. npm install react-router-dom --save
*/
// Header.js -> Component
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    const Header = () => {
      return <Fragment>
      <div class="header">
          <Link to="/about" >About us</Link>
          <Link to="/contact" >Contact us</Link>
          <Link to="/" >Home</Link>
      </div>
      <div class="body">Something...</div>
     </Fragment>;
    }
    export default Header;
    
// In your App.js file add the following
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header/>
            <Route exact path="/contact" component= {Contact}/>
            <Route exact path="/about" component = {About}/>
            <Route exact path = "/" component = { Home }/>
        <Router>
    );
```